# Можно ли свой класс созданный в C++ реализовать из dll

Tags: c++builder

Здравстуйте, я програмироваю в C++, инструмент Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.4 Version 27.0.37889.9797
Создал свой класс, и хочу его реализовать через .dll, Я программироваю в системе Windows 10, и хочу свой класс вызывать через .dll, как мне реализовать? буду презнателень если вы приведете маленький пример как это сделать, с обычным классом!!!

Comment: Поясните `хочу свой класс вызывать через .dll`

Comment: Примеру я создал один класс в c++, хочу откомпляцию сделать в .dll, а после этого хочу этот класс использывать в Делфи через .dll файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классы из dll нельзя использовать в основной программе на Delphi. Даже если dll сделана на Delphi, то экспорт классов не делают - это возможно лишь при создании BPL (packages). Иначе описание классов дублируется, но они не совпадают (известная ошибка типа `Cannot assign TFont to TFont`)

Если есть нужда в dll, то вся работа с классом инкапсулируется внутри dll, экспортируются только простые функции, **не методы класса**